# Cache OpenAI system messages to improve latency

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am using gpt-3-turbo model. I have hard coded restrictions that don't change between calls. The user messages change. I was hoping I could not resend the system message every call but have it cached so latency could be improved. Any suggestions?

```
def get_new_recommendation(problem, model="gpt-3.5-turbo"):
    # First call, include instructions and restrictions in system message
    system_message = {
        "role": "system",
        "content": "Restrictions: \n\n1. All output must be valid formatted JSON BLAH BLAH BLAH"
    }

    user_message = {
        "role": "user",
        "content": f"Problem statement:\n\n \"{problem}\""
    }

    messages = [system_message, user_message]

    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model=model,
        messages=messages,
        temperature=0
    )

    return response.choices[0].message["content"]
```

Basically hoping to not send the system message each time